# how to pass an array to another view controller in swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift

I have looked around for a good example of how to pass an array created and populated in 1 view conroller and pass it to another through a modal segue.

Here is my storyboard

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bvO2.jpg)

The user clicks the history button and it pops open the modal table view controller. The table view is then populated with the contents of an array send or passed from the original view.

When I print the contents of the array in the Destination View Controller its empty. So i think there is a problem with how its getting initialized.

Here is my code so far

This is the 1st UIView controller

```
//UIPickerView BarButtonItem done button actions here

func donePicker() {

    txtHeight.resignFirstResponder()

    var feet = Int(item1.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")[0])!
    let inches = Int(item2.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")[0])!

    feet *= 12

    let totalInches = feet + inches

    totalHeightValues.append(totalInches)

    print(totalHeightValues)

    txtHeight.text = ""

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "\(feet / 12) ft" + " " + "\(inches) in", message: "Entry Sucessfully Added", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


//UIPickerView BarButtonItem cancel button actions here

func cancelPicker() {

    txtHeight.text = ""
    txtHeight.resignFirstResponder()

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "showHistory") {

        let dVC = (segue.destinationViewController as! HistoryTableViewController)

        dVC.totalHeightValuesDest = totalHeightValues
    }

}
```

Here is the Destination or 2nd tableviewcontroller

```
import UIKit

class HistoryTableViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBAction func btnExit(sender: AnyObject) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}


var totalHeightValuesDest: [Int] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    print(totalHeightValuesDest)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return totalHeightValuesDest.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(totalHeightValuesDest[indexPath.row])"

    return cell
}
```

Comment: a) double check your segue identifier, and b) the destination VC for that segue is a navigation controller, the HistoryTableViewController will be the `topViewController` of the `segue.destinationViewController`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In the destination (HistoryTableViewController) create an array property.
2. In the first view controller in `prepareForSeque` assign the property to the array you currently have.
3. Continue with segue

In step #2, after `dVC.totalHeightValuesDest = totalHeightValues`, add the following:
`dVC.myNewArrayProperty = myCurrentArrayOfHistoryObjects`. Obviously, you'll substitute the property name you created in the HistoryViewController and the current myCurrentArrayOfHistoryObjects with the name of the local array variable you have.

Make sure to cast the destinationViewController correctly (UINavigationController first, then call topViewController to get to your HistoryViewController).

Comment: I followed your instructions and it looks exactly as it did before.  dVC.totalHeightValuesDest = totalHeightValues

Comment: @ThomasM. Sorry, code wasn't scrolling, so I couldn't see the rest of your `prepareForSegue` definition. Have you confirmed that the values when assigning them in the `prepareForSegue` method are still as you expected? If so, I'm assuming `print(totalHeightValuesDest)` in the HistoryViewController shows that the values weren't saved?

Comment: Also, where do you declare `totalHeightValues`?

Comment: I declare it publicly in the first ViewController, I keep on getting this new error. It says that id "Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x10bb58860) to '.HistoryTableViewController' (0x10a401590)." Any idea what that is about?

Comment: @ThomasM: Check the comment made by [pbasdf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37633599/how-to-pass-an-array-to-another-view-controller-in-swift#comment62749249_37633599) under your question. It solves all the issues you are facing.

Comment: Hey thanks for the feedback but it still is not fixed. There is no option for topViewController. I type it in and it gives me an error saying type UIViewConrtoller has no member topViewController

Comment: Ok now I got it working - I had to do more research on the whole topViewController thing and I ended up fixing it with this override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        
        if (segue.identifier == "showHeightHistory") {
            
            let navVC = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
            
            let tableVC = navVC.viewControllers.first as! HistoryTableViewController
            
            tableVC.totalHeightValuesDest = totalHeightValues
            
        }
        
    }

Comment: @ThomasM. Can you confirm that you can pass _something_ to the HistoryViewController? For example, create a string variable in the HistoryViewController and try passing a string in. I'm wondering if there is a different passing an Int array. I'm not well versed in Swift, as I've continued with Objective-C for now, and in Objective-C, I'd have to pass an NSArray of NSNumbers, because an array must be objects. Just not sure the difference in Swift, so I'd start with making sure you can pass something--anything--to the controller first.

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
dVC.totalHeightValuesDest = totalHeightValues
```

to

```
dVC.totalHeightValuesDest = self.totalHeightValues
```